# Stream Writer Not writing

Tags: vb.net, streamwriter

my program is not writing the log (using stream writer) when the application closes. Can anyone help explain what is going wrong?

```
    Private Sub Logs()
    Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Users\user\Desktop\SL_LOGS.txt", True)
        writer.WriteLine("Failed Attempts: " & Label2.Text)
    End Using

    Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Users\user\Desktop\SL_LOGS.txt", True)
        writer.WriteLine("Time intiated: " & Label5.Text)
    End Using

    Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Users\user\Desktop\SL_LOGS.txt", True)
        writer.WriteLine("Dispose Time: " & Label6.Text)
    End Using

    Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Users\user\Desktop\SL_LOGS.txt", True)
        writer.WriteLine("_____________________________________")
    End Using
    Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Users\user\Desktop\SL_LOGS.txt", True)
        writer.WriteLine(" ")
    End Using
End Sub
```

Thanks!

FIXED: I had my Form Closing sub before the save logs. I had changed that prior but it seemed to switch back.

Comment: all those writer.writeline statements can be put inside one USING block - no need to create a new streamwriter for each line.  when and where is this called from?

Comment: Never mind, I sorted it. It didn't seem to update when I changed a vital part of my code. Thanks!

Comment: Please either post the solution as an answer (and accept it) to help others in future or delete this question if you think it will have no value to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless, this is all you need:

```
Private Sub Logs()
Using writer As StreamWriter = _
                New StreamWriter("C:\Users\user\Desktop\SL_LOGS.txt", True)
    writer.WriteLine("Failed Attempts: " & Label2.Text)

    writer.WriteLine("Time intiated: " & Label5.Text)

    writer.WriteLine("Dispose Time: " & Label6.Text)

    writer.WriteLine("_____________________________________")

    writer.WriteLine(" ")
End Using
End Sub
```